# jittery movement while jumping unity 2d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i am using a 2 scripts, a player movement and a camera follow script. while jumping normally the jump is smooth, it is also smooth while moving my character. what i understand is that the camera follow script is somehow not allowing the jump to be smooth.here is the player movement script.

```
public class player_movement : MonoBehaviour
{
Rigidbody2D rb;
public float speed;
private float moveInput;

private bool isGrounded;
public Transform feetPos;
public float checkRadius;
public LayerMask whatIsGround;
public float jumpForce;

private float jumpTimeCounter;
public float jumpTime;
private bool isJumping;

private Animator anim;

void Start()
{
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    movement();
}

private void movement()
{
    moveInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveInput * speed, rb.velocity.y);

    if (isGrounded == false && moveInput == 0)
    {
        anim.SetBool("is running", false);
    }
    else if (isGrounded == true && moveInput != 0)
    {
        anim.SetBool("is running", true);
    }
    else if(isGrounded == true && moveInput == 0)
    {
        anim.SetBool("is running", false);
    }
    else if (isGrounded == false && moveInput != 0)
    {
        anim.SetBool("is running", false);
    }
}

void Update()
{
    isGrounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(feetPos.position, checkRadius, whatIsGround);

    if (moveInput > 0)
    {
        transform.eulerAngles = new Vector2(0, 0);
    }
    else if (moveInput < 0)
    {
        transform.eulerAngles = new Vector2(0, 180);
    }
    Jump();
}

private void Jump()
{
    if (isGrounded == true && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        isJumping = true;
        jumpTimeCounter = jumpTime;
        rb.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpForce;
    }
   


    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        if (jumpTimeCounter > 0 && isJumping == true)
        {
            rb.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpForce;
            jumpTimeCounter -= Time.deltaTime;
        }
        else
        {
            isJumping = false;
        }
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        isJumping = false;
    }
}
private void LateUpdate()
{
   //Jump();
}
}
```

and here is the camera follow script.

```
public class cammeraFollow : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject followObject;
    public Vector2 followOffset;
    public float speed = 3f;
    private Vector2 threshold;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;

void Start()
{
    threshold = calculateThreshold();
    rb = followObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void FixedUpdate()
{
    Vector2 follow = followObject.transform.position;
    float xDifference = Vector2.Distance(Vector2.right * transform.position.x, Vector2.right * follow.x);
    float yDifference = Vector2.Distance(Vector2.up * transform.position.y, Vector2.up * follow.y);

    Vector3 newPosition = transform.position;
    if(Mathf.Abs(xDifference) >= threshold.x)
    {
        newPosition.x = follow.x;
    }
    if (Mathf.Abs(yDifference) >= threshold.y)
    {
        newPosition.y = follow.y;
    }
    float moveSpeed = rb.velocity.magnitude > speed ? rb.velocity.magnitude : speed;
    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, newPosition, moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

}

private Vector3 calculateThreshold()
{
    Rect aspect = Camera.main.pixelRect;
    Vector2 t = new Vector2(Camera.main.orthographicSize * aspect.width / aspect.height, Camera.main.orthographicSize);
    t.x -= followOffset.x;
    t.y -= followOffset.y;
    return t;
}
private void OnDrawGizmos()
{
    Gizmos.color = Color.blue;
    Vector2 border = calculateThreshold();
    Gizmos.DrawWireCube(transform.position, new Vector3(border.x * 2, border.y * 2, 1));
}
}
```

can anyone help me with this one.

Comment: Try putting your camera follow code into LateUpdate method.

Answer (score 1):

FixedUpdate is not called every frame but in fixed intervals instead. It's more for physics and gameplay code.

Try changing the camera follow script to Update.

Comment: thank you for trying to help me, im flattered that you responded, but this didn't solve the problem.